# Save changes to Entity model to the database

Tags: asp.net, database, entity-framework

I'm new to Entity Framework and am expanding an existing codebase. I'm using jQuery to pass the needed info back to the server ajaxy style, so I can't use `TryUpdateModel()`. Here's the code:

```
<HttpPost()>
    Function UpdateRoster() As JsonResult
        Dim model As New Models.ViewModels.PlayerAdmin

        Dim jsonString As String = Request.Form("json")

        model = Deserialise(Of Models.ViewModels.PlayerAdmin)(jsonString)

        For Each playerAdminPlayer As Models.ViewModels.PlayerAdminPlayer In model.Roster
            Dim playerToTeam As New DAL.PlayersToTeam
            Dim player As DAL.Player = PlayerAdminManager.GetPlayerById(playerAdminPlayer.PlayerId)
            player.FirstName = playerAdminPlayer.FirstName
            PlayerAdminManager.SaveChanges()
        Next playerAdminPlayer


        Dim playerAfter As DAL.Player = PlayerAdminManager.GetPlayerById(model.Roster.First.PlayerId)

        Return Json(New With {.success = False, .message = playerAfter.FirstName})

    End Function
```

`Deserialise` is a helper function that converts the incoming JSON string to a vb object.

Things seem to work fine in that `player` successfully loads from the DB and `playerAdminPlayer` is the correct object from the JSON string. However, when I call `PlayerAdminManager.SaveChanges()` (which just passes the call the db.SaveChanges() the result is always 0, even if there is a change (not sure if that is expected).

`playerAfter` was my attempt to see if changes were actually being saved. It seems to work correctly, in that `playerAfter.FirstName` is the newly updated first name.

`PlayerAdminManager.GetPlayerById(integer)` pulls from the DB, so I would think that, since changes are observed in `playerAfter`, that those changes were saved to the DB. However, when I reload the web page (which pulls from the DB), the old values are there.

Any ideas?

Here are some of the functions I mention:

```
Function GetPlayerById(ByVal Id As Integer) As DAL.Player
        Return Container.Players.Where(Function(o) o.PlayerId = Id And o.IsVisible = True).SingleOrDefault
    End Function

Sub SaveChanges()
        Dim numberOfChanges As Integer = Container.SaveChanges()
        Debug.WriteLine("No conflicts. " & numberOfChanges.ToString() & " updates saved.")
    End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Container code:

```
 Private _Container As DAL.LateralSportsContainer
    Protected ReadOnly Property Container As DAL.LateralSportsContainer
        Get
            If _Container Is Nothing Then
                Dim connStr As New System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnectionStringBuilder
                connStr.ProviderConnectionString = Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ApplicationServices").ConnectionString
                connStr.Metadata = "res://*/Lateral.csdl|res://*/Lateral.ssdl|res://*/Lateral.msl"
                connStr.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient"
                _Container = New DAL.LateralSportsContainer(connStr.ConnectionString)
            End If

            Return _Container
        End Get
    End Property
```

Comment: Is Container a static or cached instance of your DataContext? Can you show the code related to creating and storing Container?

Comment: @wonkim00 - was that all you needed?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for, but I can't see anything wrong. I don't think it's a DataContext lifetime management issue -- it gets created and cached, and subsequent calls to methods on PlayerAdminManager use the cached instance, so change tracking should be active and attaching the modified object shouldn't be necessary. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look.  What do you mean by attaching the modified object? (I'm completely new to the Entity framework)

Comment: [How to update a detached entity in Entity Framework](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2011/03/how-to-update-detached-entity-in-entity.html)

I would also confirm that when you reload the page, that a brand new DataContext is being created. Put a breakpoint in the Container getter. If it's somehow using a cached copy, maybe calling Refresh() on the entity will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using a non static (shared) `Container.`  I had 2 `Manager` classes that both inherited from a `BaseManager` class were the `Container` was defined.  I was executing the query command in one `Manager` and saving in another.

Doh!